Hedging a long position, multiple periods (Steven E. Shreve, Stochastic Calculus for Finance I)

I have attempted to answer this question, but I'm unsure if I'm on the right track. I've started with setting the value of the portfolio at time 3 to the desired value:
$$
X_3(HHH) = X_3(HHT) = X_3(HTH) = ... = X_3(TTT) = 2.6875
$$
Using the return of the lookback option and the known values of the portfolios, I constructed my system of linear equations for time 2, for example:
$$
2.6875 = 12 \Delta_2(HH) + 1.25 X_2(HH)\\
2.6875 = -12 \Delta_2(HH) + 1.25 X_2(HT) + 8 \quad \text{//8 is the option yield}
$$
Solving this I get $\Delta_2(HH) = 1/3$ and $X_2(HH) = -1.05$.
I repeat the same process until I get to period 0, where I obtain $\Delta_0=0.98/3$ and $X_0 = -1.2$. This seems incorrect since we should start with a wealth of 0 (should we not?).
I would like to see if my approach is even correct. What's the correct solution/approach?
